# Join two tables in SQL and select certain columns

Tags: sql-server

I have a table `contacts` which has the PK fields `name` and `idref`
and another table called `links` that has the PK fields `contactFK`, `type` and `groupid`

For example

```
contacts 

pk     name    idref
1      john     5634
2      jen      4525
3      james    5656

links

pk     contactfk    type       groupid
1          1        primary    555
2          2        worker     555
3          3        primary    666
```

I want to show

```
name  id    groupid primaryid
john  5634  555     5634
jen   4525  555     5634
james 5656  666     5656
```

Comment: Please fix the formatting of your desired output, and explain why it should result, i.e. what you intend to join on.

Comment: Why do Jon and Jen have the same primaryid? Is your ouput “I want to show data” incorrect or your input data of two tables incorrect?

Comment: Hello sorry new to this I want to show the id of the primary group  member for example john is the manager of team 555  so Im showing that jen is in team 55 and john is the manager

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use a CTE to pull out the Primary Group IDs first and then join back to it for each user as such:

```
CREATE TABLE #Contacts(pk int, name varchar(50), idref int)
INSERT INTO #Contacts VALUES(1,'john', 5634), 
                            (2,'jen', 4525),
                            (3,'james', 5656)

CREATE TABLE #links(pk int, contactfk int,type varchar(20),groupid int)
        INSERT INTO #links VALUES(1,1,'primary', 555),
                                 (2,2,'worker', 555),
                                (3,3,'primary',666)



;WITH CTE AS
(SELECT t1.idref, GROUPID 
        from #Contacts t1
        INNER JOIN #links t2 on t2.contactfk = t1.pk
        where t2.[type] = 'primary'
)
SELECT t1.name, t1.idref,t2.groupid, t3.idref PrimaryID
from #Contacts t1
INNER JOIN #links t2 on t1.pk = t2.contactfk
INNER JOIN CTE t3 on t3.groupid = t2.groupid
```

Answer (score 0):

```
Select a.name, a.idref id, b.groupid primaryid from contacts a left outer join links b on a.pk = b.pk
```

Comment: sorry I was ment to put that I want to bring back the primary of a contacts goupid alongside theirs

Comment: Shouldn't you join on the `contactfk`, not the `pk` of both tables?

Comment: Potentially (OP did not specify) would result in same output per input